# How to register an icon to a file association?

Tags: vb.net

There are two file extentions called `.luo` and `.luda`.
When the program loads the `.luo` and `.luda` are assigned.
The variables `path` and `path2` contains the location to the icons.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim path, path2 As String
    path = Application.StartupPath & "ludafile.ico"
    path2 = Application.StartupPath & "luofile.ico"
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".luda").SetValue("", "Luda Solution (.luda)", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".luo").SetValue("", "Luda Page File (.luo)", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
    My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("LudaCreate\shell\open\command").SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath & " ""%l"" ", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
End Sub
```

The code above succesfully works but I want to register an icon to these files.
One icon for `.luda` and another for `.luo`.

Comment: With `CreateSubKey(".luda").SetValue("", ...)` you create an entry in `CLASSES_ROOT` with `(default)` set to `Luda Solution (.luda)`. You should instead add a reference to the application `ProgID` (usually `AppName.Association.Version` e.g. `Luda.Solution.2`, `Luda.PageFile.2`). Here, the `(default)` entry registers the full name of the Application and association (e.g., `Luda Solution`, `Luda Page File`). The `DefaultIcon` key stores the path to the associated Icon. It can be an `.ico` file or an assembly (`.exe`, `.dll`): in this case, you also specify the index of the Icon to use.

Comment: The installer can also provide this functionality. See `Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations`. It will also register the Application `CLSID`.